# python checkbutton appearance does not update after setting to 1

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a class with a member self.checkbutton (using the TkInter CheckButton), created in the init function with:

```
self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self.frame, variable=self.value, command=self.get_entry_and_execute, onvalue="1", offvalue="0")
```

Now, instead of clicking on the checkbutton in my frame, I want to set it in my code. So, from somewhere in my code, I call setvalue("1") calling this function:

```
def setvalue(self, value):
    if (value == "1"):
        print "SELECTING CHECKBUTTON"
        self.checkbutton.select()
        #   self.checkbutton.set(value=1)
```

Now, when I do this, actually, I can see that the associated "self.get_entry_and_execute" function is called and it even changes some background color. But, the checkbutton remains unchecked (i.e. an empty field without the "V" symbol). 
Weirly, when I add the command

```
        self.checkbutton.set(value=1)
```

, the code complains: *AttributeError: Checkbutton instance has no attribute 'set'*
but now the checkbutton **does** get checked!

I am assuming that because of this error, python puts the checkbutton in the correct state (=1) even though the "set" function does not exist. My question is: how can I correctly make python put the "V" inside the checkbutton box? (I.e, something like a "redraw" function).

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, `self.value` is an instance of a [variable class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), so all what you need to do is to replace `self.checkbutton.set(value=1)` by  `self.value.set(value=1)`

Comment: Yes, this works. However, what I did wrong was something else. At the end of the setvalue function I made a call to "self.checkbutton.invoke()". For some reason (???), this does a reset and after this call, the checkbutton value is set back to 0 again. I don't know why this is. When I don't call the "invoke" function, it's not even necessary to make the call to "self.value.set(value=1)". Just calling "self.checkbutton.select()" is enough. <br/> So, now my only remaining question is: why does "invoke" in such a strange way?